# How to wait for Coroutine response in Espresso test?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, kotlin-coroutines

This function is executed from my activity to check if a specific feature flag is enable, **dispatcher.io()** is injected so, for test mode the dispatcher is **Main**

```kotlin
fun isFeatureFlagEnabled(nameKey: String, completion: (enabled: Boolean) -> Unit) {
        CoroutineScope(context = dispatcher.io()).launch {
            val featureFlag = featureFlagsRepository.featureFlagsDao.getFeatureFlag(nameKey)
            if (featureFlag != null) {
                completion(featureFlag.isEnabled)
            }
            else {
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the invocation if the function in the activity

```kotlin
private fun launchClearentCardOnFileBaseOnFeatureFlag(cardNavHelper: CardNavHelper){
        featureFlagsHelper?.isFeatureFlagEnabled(CLEARENT_CARD_ON_FILE){enable ->
            if(enable){
                putFragment(
                    ClearentNativeFormFragment.newInstance(cardNavHelper))
            }else{
                putFragment(
                    ClearentCardOnFileFormFragment.newInstance(cardNavHelper))
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my test that fails because Espresso doesn't wait for the lambda function that i pass as parameter to return a response after check the database (it is an **inMemoryDatabase**)

```kotlin
@Test
    fun testFFClearentNativeFormEnable(){

        mockWebServer.setDispatcher(BusinessWithAddonsAndPaymentProcessorClearentDispatcher())


        val application = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<SchedulicityApplication>()

        runBlocking(Dispatchers.Main) {
            application.featureFlagsHelper.featureFlagsRepository.featureFlagsDao.insertFeatureFlags(
                    featureFlagsEnable
            )
        }

        intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_KEY_CARD_ON_FILE_EXTRAS, cardNavHelperFromClientRecord)
        activityTestRule.launchActivity(intent)
        
        runBlocking { delay(10000) }

        populateClearentForm(validCardNumber = false, validExpDate = true)

    }
```

I have to put this delay **runBlocking { delay(10000) }** other ways fails.
So my question is. Do you know how i can wait for the coroutine response in the UI thread so my test could pass ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [espresso idling resources](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/espresso/idling-resource).